# Where does the formula of derivative of inverse function come from?

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse-function

How can we prove this formula?

Let $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable.

$$f(x_0)=y_0\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad f^{-1}(y_0)=x_0$$

Formula of derivative of inverse function is that:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(f^{-1}\right)(y_0)=\dfrac{1}{f'(x_0)}$$

But why? Where this formula comes from?

**Idea 1:**

Using the features of inverse functions.

We accualy know that function and its inverse fuction(If it exists) show symmetric property, like given below.
[image]

Therefore, if we observe [tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent) on a point in $f$  like  $A(x_0,y_0)$  (then in inverse function mean $A'(y_0,x_0)$) ,and I think, we can say that there is relationship between $f'(x_0)$  and  $f^{-1}(y_0)$ ,but how? Here I couldn't complete.

**Idea 2:**

Definition of limit of derivative.

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=f'(x_0)$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f^{-1}(y_0+h)-f^{-1}(y_0)}{h}=\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(f^{-1}\right)(y_0)$$

Here I couldn't see any hint to prove consequence, as well...

Comment: see also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation

Comment: How can we prove this formula?

Comment: i hope this will help you http://www.math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/invfnthm.pdf

Comment: If you already know the chain rule, you can differentiate $f^{-1}\circ f$ (whichs equals the identity function).

Comment: thank you all, Git Gud and Dr.Sonnhard Graubner, I solved it :):):)

Comment: And if you can suggest other methots, I would listen :)